# Importing functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

Trying to use GoJS library I get an **"import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"** error.

**main.html**

```
...
<script id = "code">
    import {makeNodes} from "./make_nodes.js";

    function init(){
       makeNodes(model);
       ...
    }
</script>

<body onload="init()">
...
```

**make_nodes.js**

```
export function makeNodes(model){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't use `import` except in a module. Your code isn't in a module. To make it a module, use `type="module"` in the `script` tag:

```
<script id = "code" type = "module">
```

All modern browsers natively support modules (Obsolete ones like Internet Explorer don't, and never will.)

Despite that native support, though, most people using `import`/`export` syntax are still doing so via transpilers and/or bundlers (like Vite, Rollup, Webpack, Browserify, ...).

Once you're actually using a module, `init` will no longer be a global, but your `<body onload="init()">` expects `init` to be a global. (This is one of several reason not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers.) To fix that, hook up the event in your code, removing the `onload` attribute from `<body>`:

```
function init(){
   makeNodes(model);
   // ...
}
window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

**However**, the `load` event you're using happens very, very late in the page load process, waiting for all images and other resources to finish loading. In most cases, [you're better off](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) not doing that. Modules are always deferred, so they don't run until the HTML of the page has been parsed into the DOM, which is usually all you need. (We used to have to put `script` tags at the very end of the `body` element instead, but then the `defer` attribute was added for scripts, and again all `type="module"` scripts are deferred automatically.)

Here's an exmaple — notice that the `script type="module"` is **above** the elements its code operates on, and yet it works just fine (because it's deferred):

```html
<script type="module">
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Button clicked");
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

That wouldn't work with a non-module script unless you added the `defer` attribute.